# PropertyChanged not affected on collection changes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dictionary, inotifypropertychanged

I use the following dictionary:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> _myDic;
public Dictionary<string, string> MyDic
{
   get
   {
       return _myDic;
   }
   set
   {
      if (_myDic!= value)
      {
         _myDic= value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged("MyDic");
      }
    }
}
```

Is bind to a combobox in my view.

Everything works.

The problem is that when I add item is not updated if already **opened** the combobox.

Only if it remains **closed** from the beginning then the change appears on the screen.

I have a single place where I add item to dictionary and immediately I used the event `propertychanged` hoping it will affect the UI:

```
MyDic.Add(strK, strV);
NotifyPropertyChanged("MyDic");
```

But it did not help (although the event did not coming null).

I understand that it is because it is a change in the collection, not the object itself. My problem is that I can not change the type of this variable to cutsom ObservableDictionary for various reasons.

My question is why the  `NotifyPropertyChanged("MyDic");` is not affected. And is there any other way (except to change the type) to deal with this problem?

Comment: Have you tried to do the same with the Count property of the dictionary?

Comment: @user2760623. What does this mean to do the same with the Count property of the dictionary? You can expand?

Comment: To notify the change in the Dictionary.Count property.

Comment: What do you mean by the notification being "not affected"?

Comment: @JonSkeet. I mean the list in the UI not changed if already opened the combobox.

Comment: @user2760623. I try it. It also did not help.

Comment: Show code where you tried to rebind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way a bit primitive. And yet it worked.

I created another dictionary which I added the item to it.

Then I changed my dictionary to the local dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> _dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var str in MyDic)
   _dic.Add(str.Key, str.Value);
 _dic.Add(strK, strV);
  MyDic= _dic;
```

**If someone has a better way I'd love to hear.**